# Inequality on bounded matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality

Consider a matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, for which all elements $R_{i,j}$ are bounded as $0\le R_{i,j}\le1$. We define the following variables:

$\displaystyle SP=\prod_{j=1}^n \left[1-\prod_{i=1}^m \left(1-R_{i,j}\right)\right] $

and

$\displaystyle PS=1-\prod_{i=1}^m \left(1-\prod_{j=1}^n R_{i,j}\right) $

Can one prove that it always holds $SP\ge PS$?

For context: I came up with this conjecture while considering some questions on probability theory. I am rather sure this result is either already known or easily proven from general theorems, but I cannot find a reference nor devise a simple proof. However, I have numerically verified that the inequality holds for a large number of random matrices.

How would one prove this inequality?